# How do you cross probability distributions to get a new distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a research problem that I’ve been struggling with. I have a relatively shaky foundation of advanced maths. I have a few hundred populations of fish and each population has its own distribution of the number of fish eggs that will hatch that looks something like this:

```
Phatch=[ 0.112444598019254
0.0856999741439462
0.186341760331494
0.184493363005953
0.158063215672192
0.0315656900693706
0.00509668002379916
0.132368893713043
0.0711257331094643
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
]
```

There is also the probability that some of them will get eaten by predators:
[that is a matrix that looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAzqJ.png)

It's essentially a matrix of the fish that can get eaten by the maximum number of fish that could hatch. So, for a population that only hatches 1 fish, there is a 0.48 chance that 0 will get eaten and 0.52 chance that 1 will get eaten. So each column sums to 1.

I was told that in order to create distribution of surviving fish, I need to "cross" these probabilities so that I end up with a single distribution (that sums to 1) for the remaining fish. What is(are) the formula(s) or equations I would use to do this? 'Phatch' changes for every population (so I'd essentially iterate through all the possible Phatch distributions against the same 'eaten by predators' matrix).

I tried good ol' Google, but maybe my terminology is incorrect because I can't find any similar examples. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns of your matrix each sum to 1. It contains the *conditional probabilities* that some number of eggs are eaten, given that a certain number of eggs were hatched.

Multiply the numbers in the first first column by 0.085; multiply the numbers in the second column by 0.186; etc. This will produce a matrix whose entries all sum to one. The cell in the $i$th column and $j$th row is the probability that "$i$ eggs hatch and $j$ were eaten." This is known as the "joint distribution" of number of eggs hatched and number eaten.

From the joint distribution, you can find other distributions. For example if you want a distribution for "number of eggs eaten" you can sum each row.

Comment: But the columns are already the distribution for number of eggs eaten. I was told the output wouldn't be a matrix, but another 1x21 array of values, like phatch. Conceptually, I'm trying to achieve the probability of hatched fish - distribution of eaten fish = distribution of surviving fish.

Comment: @user89092 After you do the column multiplication I mentioned in the second paragraph,  you'll need to sum cells based on the number of surviving fish. For example, for 4 surviving fish, you'll sum the (4 hatched, 0 eaten), (5 hatched, 1 eaten), (6 hatched, 2 eaten), etc. cells.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a million!